# Open chrome options from popup

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

When I run my code, it comes up with "about blank" instead of my extension options. I would like it to open the options in front of the extensions. Here is some of my extension code-

popup.js:

```
document.getElementById('div_options').onclick = openOps;
function openOps() {
       window.open("chrome://extensions/?options=pgapbgeppkbeghldobmjehpbdleapdip");
       closeAndReloadPopup();
    };
```

popup.html:

```
<li>
    <a href="#"><div id="div_options">Options</div></a>
</li>
```

manifest.json:

```
{   
"background": {
        "page": "background.html"
    },
"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'",
"page_action": {
          "default_icon": {
            "19": "images/icon19.png",
            "38": "images/icon38.png"
          },
          "default_title": "Scratch theme loader",
          "default_popup": "popup.html"
        },
"options_ui": {
            "page": "options.html",
            "chrome_style": true
        },
"web_accessible_resources": ["src/options/options.html"],
    "permissions": [
        "tabs",
        "storage",
        "declarativeContent",
        "https://scratch.mit.edu/*",
        "https://pastebin.com/raw/*"
    ]
}
```

options.html:

```
<html>
    <stuff>
</html>
```

Comment: In general, don't use `window.open` in extensions. Rely on `chrome.tabs` and `chrome.windows`, creation does not require permissions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the recommended way: `chrome.runtime.openOptionsPage(callback)`

> Open your Extension's options page, if possible. The precise behavior
>   may depend on your manifest's options_ui or options_page key, or what
>   Chrome happens to support at the time. For example, the page may be
>   opened in a new tab, within chrome://extensions, within an App, or it
>   may just focus an open options page. It will never cause the caller
>   page to reload. If your Extension does not declare an options page, or
>   Chrome failed to create one for some other reason, the callback will
>   set lastError.

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-openOptionsPage

Alternatively, `chrome.tabs.create({ url: "chrome://extensions/?options=" + chrome.runtime.id }, callback)` or `chrome.tabs.create({ url: "options.html" }, callback)`

Comment: Thanks this worked well when I added a few more callback functions.